# Build numpy dtype form string (without eval)?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to build/parse a numpy dtype string e.g.

```
dtype_string = "[('a', '<i4', (100,)), ('b', '>i4')]"
```

and use it like

```
np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=get_me_my_dtype(dtype_string))
```

I know that eval() works (as get_me_my_dtype()), but i do not want to use it here due to the security implications. Any suggestions about a secure alternative?

Cheers, Marius

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/247805) to me. *Why* are you constructing the dtype from a string?

Comment: @ali_m I would like to implement a custom (de)serializer for numpy arrays. Therefore i would also like to (de)serialize the dtype of a numpy array without using a full blown eval() for this.

Comment: Why not just serialize and deserialize the list of tuples?

Comment: `'uint8'`    is also a valid dtype. The logic to catch all cases would be considerable and i was wondering if there is a _cheaper_ alternative.

Comment: Any numpy dtype can be expressed as a list of tuples, e.g. `np.dtype('uint8').descr` will give you `[('', '|u1')]`.

Comment: `np.dtype([('', '|u1')])` => `dtype([('f0', 'u1')])`, while
`np.dtype('uint8')` => `dtype('uint8')`, which looks at least different from the user perspective. Thanks for the tip about .descr though

Comment: OK, fair point, but you could avoid this unwanted conversion by serializing the dtype object itself.

Comment: That's kind of what i want to to, so i "serialize" calling str(np_dtype) and get back the dtype by calling save_eval(dtype_string). This way i am independent of the python pickle mechanics (if this is what you mean by serialize the dtype object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should *safely* do the trick:

```
>>> import ast
>>> dtype_string = "[('a', '<i4', (100,)), ('b', '>i4')]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(dtype_string)
[('a', '<i4', (100,)), ('b', '>i4')]
```